# "Vitamin B" = Beziehungen

Tags: word-usage

Im Netz habe ich folgende Beispielsätze gefunden:

> Ohne Vitamin B kann man beruflich sowieso nichts erreichen.
>
> Vitamin B schadet doch nicht.
>
> Dass er es so weit gebracht hat, verdankt er zu einem nicht
>   unwesentlichen Teil dem Faktor Vitamin B.

Ich wurde gefragt, ob *Vitamin B* in Kombination mit dem Verb *haben* auftreten kann. Die Kursteilnehmerin bildete den folgenden Satz: *Peter hatte Vitamin B, deshalb hat er diesen Job bekommen*.
Ich schlug vor: *Peter ist über Vitamin B an diesen Job gekommen*.

Nach dem Unterricht überkamen mich Zweifel: War das Beispiel meiner Kursteilnehmerin korrekt? Kann man Vitamin B *haben*?

Answer (score 5):

Da der Ausdruck *Vitamin B* sowieso relativ Umgangssprachlich ist, gibt es wohl keine genaue Regelung dazu. 
Ich habe bisher noch nie von einer Verknüpfung von *haben* mit dem Ausdruck *Vitamin B* gehört, und nach meinem Sprachgefühl ist da auch ein kleiner Misston drin.

Wenn man mal vom Wortursprung der Vitamine an sich ausgeht: 
Man kann Vitamine ja normalerweise auch nicht *haben*, sondern nimmt sie zu sich oder bleibt *durch Vitame* oder *dank Vitaminen* gesund.
Geht man von Nahrungsmitteln aus, so spricht man auch eher von *Vitamin C enthalten* anstatt *Vitamin C haben*, zumindest wenn man von spezifischen Vitaminen spricht.

Comment: Man kann durchaus Vitamine haben, Beispiel: "Der Arzt sagt, ich habe zu wenig Vitamin D im Blut"

Comment: @Lehue   Der entscheidende Unterschied zwischen "Vitamin C im Blut haben" (wohlgeformter Ausdruck) und "Vitamin C haben" (nicht wohlgeformt) ist, dass in der wohlgeformten Formulierung die Ortsangabe enthalten ist. Nach dem etablierten Sprachempfinden erfordert "[einen Stoff] haben" zwingend eine Ortsangabe. Spezieller Fall: Frage an den Apotheker: "Haben Sie Vitamin C?" - Hier ist der Ort bzw. implizit klar und kann als mitgedacht verstanden werden: "... im Angebot" bzw. "... auf Lager."

Answer (score 3):

Wie schon in der Überschrift erkannt steht Vitamin B umgangsprachlich für Beziehungen, [bzw](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Vitamin%20B&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou).

> gute Beziehungen, die einem Vorteile verschaffen

Meiner Meinung nach spricht nichts dagegen Wortkombinationen, die mit *(gute) Beziehungen* möglich/gebräuchlich sind, auf *Vitamin B* zu übertragen.

Etwa in den drei Beispielsätzen

> Ohne Beziehungen kann man beruflich sowieso nichts erreichen.
>
> Gute Beziehungen schaden doch nicht.
>
> Dass er es so weit gebracht hat, verdankt er zu einem nicht unwesentlichen Teil dem Faktor Beziehungen.

Die Frage ist nun, ob man *(gute) Beziehungen haben* kann. Und in diesem Zusammenhang nur im Bereich des Fragenkontexts des Arbeits-Bereichs, denn natürlich kann man

> mit dem Partner/der Partnerin eine gute Beziehung haben
>
> eine gute Beziehung zum Nachbarn haben

aber hiernach ist nicht gefragt.

Übertragen wir den Beispielsatz: "Peter hatte Vitamin B, deshalb hat er diesen Job bekommen." in

> Peter hatte Beziehungen, deshalb hat er diesen Job bekommen.

könnte man den Satz so interpretieren wie die Kursteilnehmerin es gemacht hat. Allerdings kann man den Satz auch mit Beziehungen im Sinne von (sexuellen) Partnerschaften verstehen. (Ich bin mir darüber im Klaren, dass man die drei Beispielsätze oben ähnlich interpretieren könnte)

Idiomatischer und ich denke viel weiter verbreitet ist:

> Peter verfügte über Beziehungen, deshalb hat er diesen Job bekommen.

wie im bekannten

> Er verfügte über Beziehungen bis in die höchsten Kreise.

Dementsprechend kann man diesen Satz eher schreiben als

> Peter verfügte über Vitamin B, deshalb hat er diesen Job bekommen.

Ich würde also sagen, dass man Vitamin B zwar in Pillenform haben kann. Um im Job weiterkommen sollte man aber besser darüber [verfügen](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%BCber%20vitamin%20b%20verf%C3%BCgen%22&oq=%22%C3%BCber%20vitamin%20b%20verf%C3%BCgen%22). Dennoch gibt es viele Beispiele, für "[Vitamin B haben](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vitamin%20b%20haben%22%20job&oq=%22vitamin%20b%20haben%22%20job)" in ähnlicher Form wie die Kursteilnehmerin es nutzte ... darum: [es geht wohl beides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvNAO.gif) und der Satz war *ok* ;) .